# UIWebView not loading with .xib

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

For my iphone app, I am setting up a `tabBarContoller` with one of the tabs displaying a webView (`PDFViewController`).

The problem I am running into is `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "PDFViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'`

ok, I can set up this webView no problem in another project of mine with a storyboard, so I know the issue is with the `nib` file.

In my app delegate I set up the VC (so I can place it in the `tabBarController`

```
PDFViewController *pdfVC = [[PDFViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
  pdfVC.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"second"];

  NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:frontPageNavController, campusNavController, opinionNavController, sportsNavController, pdfVC, nil];

self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;
```

In my .xib I just have a view set up.

here is my `PDFViewController.m` :

```
@implementation PDFViewController 

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
  self = [super initWithNibName:@"PDFViewController" bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
  if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.bounds.size.width,self.view.bounds.size.height)];

  NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://issuu.com/miamistudent/docs"];
  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
  [webView loadRequest:request];

  [self.view addSubview:webView];
}
```

Any idea what could be causing this error? I tried setting up a normal ViewController in my PDFViewController.xib - but that didnt seem to help any. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- right click on your view and set reference outlet to your file owners
  view
- Else go to your target-> build phases-> copy bundle resource  check if the .Xib is there or not if not add it.

Comment: I took your advice - and I am trying to connect the view to the File Owner - however it is not allowing me to. Whenever I drag it to `File Owner` and let go - it just won't connect to the File owner - any idea why it is not letting me? Thanks amar.

Answer (score 0):

In your nib file you must connect view with viewcontroller, because PDFViewController expects view.